# Formal definition of plane

Tags: soft-question, 3d

The formal definition of plane says that:

A plane is a set of points such that if any two points are taken on it, all the points lying on the line joining these two points also lie on the plane.

The definition is not very intuitive(to me). How does this definition specify a plane, i.e., why are we led to believe that a set of points possessing the above property is actually a  plane?

Comment: That does not seem like a good definition of a plane, since it works just as well for (e.g.) three dimensional space.

Comment: That doesn't.  That property is true of any $n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many planes that intersect any given line. So we can not define a plane by two points alone, as you seem to be suggesting. Two points define/determine a line, since all points lying on the line connecting the two points necessarily also lie on that line. Period. So the "formal definition" you give is incorrect.

You need *three* **non-collinear** points to determine/define a plane.

Comment: Needs an UV -->> +1

Comment: Thanks for the support, @Amzoti!

Comment: I didn't make it up(Of course I can't!)-that's what my book says. And yes, 3 non-collinear points do specify a plane.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you made it up, Shubham! And of course it should seem unintuitive, because if that's what your text says, it's just "plane" wrong (no pun intended)! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...this looks more like the definition of a convex set. For example, let $D$ be the unit disk in the plane. Then for any two points in $D$ the line segment joining those two points are also in $D$.

Comment: even if you say that the entire line passing through these two points is in the set, you still dont have a plane. It could be a line. The post below is correct.